# Streaming tags script

Tags: javascript, tags, streaming

I don't know what to do anymore with this code. I tried innerHTML, DIV call but nothing makes it to show tags in my HTML page. Can anyone help me please? I need to show "musica_atual".

```
$.getJSON('http://srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS', function(data) {
    var status = data.status; // Mostra o status da rádio
    var porta = data.porta; // Mostra a porta da rádio
    var porta_dj = data.porta_dj; // Mostra a porta DJ da rádio
    var ip = data.ip; // Mostra o endereço do servidor da rádio
    var ouvintes_conectados = data.ouvintes_conectados; // Mostra total de ouvintes conectados
    var titulo = data.titulo; // Mostra o nome da rádio
    var plano_ouvintes = data.plano_ouvintes; // Mostra o limite de ouvintes do plano
    var plano_ftp = data.plano_ftp; // Mostra o limite de espaço do AutoDJ do plano
    var plano_bitrate = data.plano_bitrate; // Mostra o bitrate do plano
    var musica_atual = data.musica_atual; // Mostra a música atual
    var proxima_musica = data.proxima_musica; // Mostra a próxima música do AutoDJ(não é valido para transmissão ao vivo)
    var genero = data.genero; // Mostra o genero da rádio
    var shoutcast = data.shoutcast; // Mostra a URL do shoutcast
    var rtmp = data.rtmp; // Mostra a URl do RTMP para uso em players próprios(se tiver RTMP)
    var rtsp = data.rtsp; // Mostra a URl do RTSP para uso em players próprios(se tiver RTMP)
    var capa_musica = data.capa_musica; // Mostra a URL da imagem JPG da capa do album da música
});
```

Comment: Explain yourself a little better please. What are you trying to accomplish in your HTML, remember to add minimal complete and verifiable samples

Comment: I want to put the var musica_atual in the body section. I need to show the information there. It has informations that I need to show in the page. If you open this link (http://srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS) you'll see that there's informations showing... But I don't know how to call it in the html content.

Comment: So you store it into a variable. Where are you using that variable to show the content in the page?

Comment: And do you have a specific markup to show this information?

Comment: I tried to use innerHTML here "var musica_atual.innerHTML = data.musica_atual;" and tried to call it with a DIV "<div id="musica_atual"></div>"

Comment: Ensure you wait for the DOM to load => http://jsbin.com/yujugureme/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The code I have... Is it totally wrong? Is there any way to make the js update this song name without refreshing the page? Thanks for the help!

Comment: My link does that, clicking *run with js* is the page loading for the first time.

Comment: @AlexK. I clicked! But it doesn't keeps updating...
Automatically, I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on what we talked, check if this works for you: [Click to see jsFiddle here (UPDATED)](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsotobianco/mpsf9L6v/)

**Javascript code**

```
/* The url has a // to let the browser decide whether to use HTTP o HTTPS */
var response = $.getJSON('//srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS', addHTML);

function addHTML(data) {

  // Getting the HTML elements to write in
  var cs = document.getElementById('current-song');
  var g = document.getElementById('genre');

  // Setting data attributes to HTML
  cs.innerHTML = data.musica_atual;
  g.innerHTML = data.genero;

}
```

**HTML markup**

```
<div>
  <span id="genre"></span>
  <h1 id="current-song"></h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Good but I need to connect here [link](http://srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS) to get the json informations. Can't copy.

Like this: $(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = data.musica_atual;
  });
});
-- by @AlexK --

Comment: I just edited the jsFiddle and it is working. I think this will work for you. Let me know!

Comment: Cool! :D Works fine too! Is there anyway to make it refresh the current song without refreshing the page? I have no idea how to do it. I'm not so in about JS. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. But that doubt must be posted in other question. If this answer was correct mark it as solved (green check mark). I'm glad to help